# Any Suggestions to what pl-sql to use to extract huge volume of records (Six million) from Oracle 10G database taking a join from multiple tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any suggestions on how to extract 6 million records from an oracle10g ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597857/any-suggestions-on-how-to-extract-6-million-records-from-an-oracle10g)

Any Sample pl-sql code on the same will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to extract to another format, XML or Comma Separated perhaps?  A little more information here would be appreciated.

Comment: Lots of time?  If you have a lot of rows that you are selecting, especially with many joins, you probably just have to wait a long time for the query to finish.

Comment: Definitely need more information.  What is the target format?  Do you have an Enterprise Edition license?  What is the outline of the query?

Comment: Yes, I have to fetch these millions of record taking a join from many tables and dump them to a flat file. I am just looking for a optimized way to do this. I think fetching 6 million of record in a single go shouldn't be a better approach to do this.

Comment: Please do **not** ask the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597857/any-suggestions-on-how-to-extract-6-million-records-from-an-oracle10g

Answer (score 1):

Hummm... `SELECT`?